# Git's equivalent of CVS's checkout or update?

Tags: git

OK, so I `add`ed and `commit`ted an entire subdirectory to git (no `push` yet, still local, to `.git`).

I then deleted the entire subdirectory. (`.git` is still there.)

I now want it back, from git. How do I do that?

I tried `git checkout` but it only lists the delete files in that subdirectory.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do `git checkout subdirname`

---

You can also do `git checkout -- subdirname`

The `--` is used to avoid ambiguity ( like say if you had a branch that was named `subdirname` and other corner cases.) Below is a snippet from man for `git checkout`:

If you have an unfortunate branch that is named hello.c, this step would be confused as an instruction to switch to that branch. You should instead write:

```
$ git checkout -- hello.c
```

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform `git checkout -- file_path` to restore it. Note the `git checkout -- a_file_name` syntax lets you retrieve not only deleted files/dirs, but their original (last committed) form before any modification. So if you wanted to undo any local modifications to a_changed_file, `git checkout -- a_changed_file` will work for this use case as well.

`--` is recommended to avoid problems with bad filenames, such as those starting with a hyphen. It also removes ambiguity in the case of a branch and a file sharing the same name.

The [git community book's chapter on undoing](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html) is a good reference for related questions.

Comment: `git checkout subdirname` worked great. What's that `--` in the middle?

Comment: `git checkout subdirname` will not handle all filenames correctly, such as those that begin with a hyphen. `git checkout -- subdirname` is recommended for this reason in the [git community book's chapter on this topic](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html)

Comment: @WinWin - The `--` is used to avoid ambiguity ( like say if you had a branch that was named `subdirname` and other corner cases. See my updated answer.

Comment: @manojlds, I never thought about the ambiguity reason. Is it not true that it fixes the problem of files like -b being interpreted as switches as well? Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Shelhamer - you are absolutely right. Of course, this is true for any bash command, not just git. That is why I said `other corner cases`. In git, resolving ambiguity is the more frequent usage though.